# how to open a .hbk files which contains the sms backup from htc one s

Tags: sms, backup

I can't open the backup of sms because after sending it on my mail I discovered it's a hbk file. How can you open this type of file?

I need to print them! thanks

Comment: Have you seen this [blog entry](http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/28/SMS-Backup-And-Restore-On-HTC-Devices) about it?

Comment: Does renaming the file with a different extension work, like *.txt or *.zip?

Answer (score 2):

In case you no longer have a copy of the SMS on your phone, but have backed-up the SMS to your PC or email, you need a combination of [t0mm13b](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/4003/t0mm13b)'s comment and [bmdixon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&feature=search_result#?t=W10)'s answer.

As  mentioned, it's not possible to open .hbk files on the PC. What you can do is:

1. Restore the .hbk to your phone as SMS

   - In your SD card, make sure you have a folder called `sms_backup`. If this doesn't exist, create it. This will be in the same level as the `Android` folder.
   - Copy the .hbk file to the `sms_backup` folder
   - Restore the SMS from the SMS settings
2. Export the SMS as .xml using [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&feature=search_result#?t=W10)
3. Email the .xml file to your PC
4. After downloading the .xml file, open it from a program like Notepad or Microsoft word, and print.

Take note that XML has a weird structure, so expect to see a lot of tags (in greater than and less than signs).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to open this file on your computer. It can only be read by the HTC SMS app.
If you still have the sms on your phone you could install [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&feature=search_result#?t=W10) which will allow you to back them up as xml which you can then print from your pc.