# How do I get the contents of an HTC .hbk file... without buying an HTC phone?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, htc

I broke the USB port of my HTC One phone, so I am unable to charge it any longer.

Before the battery was dead, I made all the needed backups, including SMS, which created an .hbk file. I searched for a solution, but the only one I can find [consists of](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50758/115599) putting this file on another HTC phone and recover the messages this way.

As I have no intention to buy a new HTC phone *just to get my messages*, how do I extract the contents of the .hbk file on a PC (Linux or Windows)?

Comment: Do you still have the ROM containing the HTC SMS app(s)?

Comment: @Robert: not sure if I understand your question. The same ROM as the one which was installed on my phone is available from the official website. Do you mean I can use it with an emulator to get back the messages?

Comment: If you still have the ROM you could extract the SMS app that created the backup. With the APK of the app that created the backup it is possible to decompile to see how the data is stored and if it is encrypted. May be the backup format is simple and a small script could decrypt/extract the SMS.

Comment: I see. It could work, indeed. Could you please promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: I would not call this an answer, it is more a rough idea. Anyway you still need someone who decompiles, understands the code and can make use of it in a new program or script. Therefore it is not doable for most users here.